# Is there an event for after a product is saved only in admin?

Tags: product, adminhtml, event-observer, magento-1

So I'm looking for an event for after a product is saved in the admin interface? Similar to `catalog_product_prepare_save` (which is before save).

It's important that it doesn't fire when e.g. another module does `$product->save()`. It should only fire when a someones saving a product manually using the  admin interface.

Or any thoughts on other solutions of course.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no special event for saving the product from the admin interface, but you can use the general `catalog_product_save_after` and add a constraint to it based on the request.
Something like this:

```
public function catalogProductSaveAfter($observer) {
    if ($actionInstance = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()) {
        $action = $actionInstance->getFullActionName();
        if ($action == 'adminhtml_catalog_product_save') { //if on admin save action
            //do your magic here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Will it not also work to define the event observer to listen via adminhtml in config.xml as well (as apart from global?)

Comment: @ProxiBlue. Yes and no. It will work on a clean install, but it will not work if you have other modules that call `$product->save()` from the backend. I mean the code in the event will be executed for those modules also. Using this verification it should be only executed in the admin product save page.

Comment: gotcha, as OP had requested, he was only interested in the admin panel product save, not the ->save() call on products in general across all admin areas - important bit of info I missed there ;)

Comment: But keep in mind that ```getAction()``` may or may not be an object, depending on where the event is triggered.

Comment: @frigg. Hmmm...that' may be possible. But can you give an example?

Comment: I have custom module that imports products using ```$product->save()```. When this is triggered I got an fatal error saying "cannot call getFullActionName() on non-object".

Comment: @frig Right. I will modify a bit the answer to fit all cases.

Comment: Marius? is there is any observer which fire only if product is edit.
admin click on edit button and if admin change any thing then is fire otherwise no.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_catalog_product_save`, which is triggered after this action, but you should make sure that the product actually has been saved because the event will also be triggered if there was an error during save:

```
$product = Mage::registry('product');
if ($product && ! $product->hasDataChanges()) {

    // product has been saved

}
```

Explanation: `_hasDataChanges` is reset to `false` after a successful save.

Answer (score 1):

You can place `catalog_product_save_after` observer withing adminhtml tag of your module config.xml to make sure that will fire on product save from admin only

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    ...
    <adminhtml>
        ...
        <events>
            <catalog_product_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <product_save_after_observer>
                        <class>StackOverflow_CustomModule_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>productSaveAfter</method>
                    </product_save_after_observer>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_after>
        </events>
        ...
    </adminhtml>
    ...
</config>
```